# Updating Array Through Constructor

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    static int[] x = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    static int z = 10;
    static int c = 20;
    static int v = 30;
    static int b = 40;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x[0]);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }



    public Program()
    {
        x = new int[4]{z, c, v, b};

    }
```

In this code snippet, I'm trying to update an array with different variables through a constructor. However, when I debug, it only prints the original [0] index. 

I have a feeling I'm doing something really stupid and I'm just tired, but could anyone tell me why the array is not updating?

Comment: your constructor is nowhere called there... either you do the changes in a `static Program() { }` constructor, or you do `new Program()` to execute the instance constructor

Comment: And then use collections for dynamic issues? That makes sense. Thank you

Comment: @kmartmvp - If it's going to be dynamic why not use a `List<T>` instead of converting to and from an array? (I assume `dynamic` refers to changes in the number of items)

Comment: I was really just messing around here. When something pops into my head, I hop onto my computer and do it. I'm new to probramming in general, so I often just try and do "problems" that enter my mind. The dynamic List<T> would for sure be better.

Comment: @kmartmvp - That's fine, I was just wondering if I was missing something :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating and operating on static data so you need the static constructor.

```
        static int[] x = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        static int z = 10;
        static int c = 20;
        static int v = 30;
        static int b = 40;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //since its static data you can easily update array here
            //x = new int[] { z, c, v, b };
            Console.WriteLine(x[0]);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static Program()
        {
            x = new int[4] { z, c, v, b };

        }
```

this will print out the 10.

This will print 5 and 10,5 of the non-static array and 10 of the static array,by creating a static variable of type program it will call the default constructor.

```
    class Program
    {
        private static Program MyInstance = new Program();
        int[] y = { 5, 6, 7, 8 };
        static int[] x = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        static int z = 10;
        static int c = 20;
        static int v = 30;
        static int b = 40;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x[0]);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static Program()
        {
            x = new int[4] { z, c, v, b };

        }

        public Program()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(y[0]);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 8):

You're not creating an object of type `Program`, so the constructor never runs.

Comment: I knew it was something incredibly stupid that I looked over somehow. Wow. Well thank you lol.